# CMake does not find OpenCV

Tags: opencv, cmake

I seem to have an issue with my CMakeLists and opencv. 
I am currently using opencv version 2.4 which is confirmed by

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv

2.4.8
```

and

```
dpkg -l libopencv*
```

which outputs http://pastebin.com/ZJEfLjDX

But for some reason when i `cmake` a simple program such as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Will `cmake` not continue due to this error.

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVModules.cmake:183 (message):
  The imported target "opencv_core" references the file

     "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libopencv_core3.so.3.1.0"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVModules.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVConfig.cmake:86 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

with this CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

The project has no `ros` dependency, and I have no idea why it is looking for `OpenCVConfig.cmake` inside `ros`.

A simple `locate` shows that the correct version is available other places

```
locate OpenCVConfig.cmake

/home/k/opencv/opencv-2.4.8/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake
/home/k/opencv/opencv-2.4.8/build/unix-install/OpenCVConfig.cmake
/home/k/opencv/opencv-2.4.8/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake
/home/k/opencv/opencv-2.4.8/cmake/templates/OpenCVConfig.cmake.in
/opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVConfig.cmake
/usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake
/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake
```

but why does it choose to use the one from `ros`, which I am not sure is even an option if I don't have `opencv3.1.0-dev` installed?

I know that a solution to this problem would be `SET` the path.  But why can't `find_package` make use of the 2.4.8 version? I even tried to change the filename of /`opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVConfig.cmake` to `/opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVConfig.cmake.old`, which caused the same error?... Why is `cmake` not able to find `opencv` by simple using `find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )`, and how do I make it so that it possible to find using this.

Comment: Path `/opt/ros/indigo` is probably added to [User Package Registry](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#user-package-registry), this registry is searched before system-wide one. According to error message `this file does not exist`, opencv installation into `/opt/ros/indigo` is broken somehow. So you may completely clean that installation (that is, remove `/opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVConfig.cmake` too), and reconfigure your project. Do not forget to clean CMake cache before reconfiguration for erase previous search results.

Comment: So what solved the problem was a simple sudo updatedb

Comment: Hi, Could you please explain how did you solve this? I'm having the same issue with ROS Kinetic and openCV.